# Install Spree Commerce on cPanel Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cpanel, spree

Sorry I'm a newbie with Ruby on Rails. I have a cPanel Server with ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.10.I downloaded Spree Commerce from GitHub and upload them to public_html. But what's next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend installing Spree Commerce on a cPanel Hosting for the following reasons

1. It takes really a lot and lot of time and effort to do so
2. Really requires a strong experience to implement in cPanel environment and even though it is waste to invest time on that
3. I Hardly doubt if anyone recommends it

Deciding Spree deployment on a cPanel hosting is not a wise decision and better prefer any other deployment method.

Alternatively i would recommend getting a VPS from any hosting company if that suits your budget and try deploying on VPS instance .

There is also "Deploying to Heroku" guide specifically built for situations like that.

Also , have you tried sandbox available from Spreecommerce . Even though it wouldn't allow you to install extensions you can try that too to get a feel out of the box for free.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation I'll reinstall the VPS with a fresh non cPanel VPS just CentOS and I'll install Spree on it following the guider.